# Enabling lower values in an equation to give a greater probability

Tags: probability

I am given the equation
$p_{ij} = N \times D_{ij} \times S_{ij} \times M_{ij} \times (1-n_{ij})$.

where

$p_{ij}$ - the probability a particle will move in a direction $(i,j)$,

$N$ -  is a normalization factor to ensure the sum of the probabilities = $1$,

$M_{ij}$ - the preferred direction of movement,

$S_{ij}$ - value assigned to a static floor field,

$D_{ij}$ - value assigned to a dynamic floor field

$n_{ij} =0$ for an empty cell, $n_{ij}=1$ for a cell that is occupied.

In the above, the greater the value of $M_{ij}$, $D_{ij}$ & $S_ij$ is obviously going to give a higher probability of movement in the direction $(i,j)$.

The way I have set up my model is that smaller values for $S_{ij}$, $D_{ij}$ and $M_{ij}$ will need to give a greater probability of moving in the direction $(i,j)$. Would the way I would then represent the eqn then simply  be

$p_{ij} =  \frac{N(1-n_{ij})}{D_{ij} \times S_{ij} \times M_{ij}}$

I think it's that simple but would greatly appreciate confirmtion.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to read the question as it is written. Put dollar signs \$ in front of all the variables and parentheses $\{ \}$ around subscripts. Here is a mathjax tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks Pedro, first time posting here, much appreciated.